# Can I use a .rc resource file on a C# project?

Tags: c#, resource-files

I have a solution in C# and i need to update the version in the resource files (.resx files are xml files), i already did it in C++ resource files (not xml files) and I want to know if I can use something like that in my C# project.

Comment: It's like to say can I use .cpp file in C#

Comment: @Saeed Not really: Win32 resources are a low-level part of the Windows EXE format. Any platform that supports EXEs can also support Win32 resources; it's just harder with C# than C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it directly from Visual Studio.

If you invoke the `csc` compiler directly, you can embed a .res file using the `/win32res:` flag on the command line. (Use the `rc` tool to generate a .res from a .rc.)

Alternatively, you could build your EXE through Visual Studio as normal, then add a post build step that invokes `ildasm` followed by `ilasm`. `ilasm` supports the `/resource=` command line flag.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, but there are some ways to convert, see this link: [Building Managed Resources from Win32 Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289497%28VS.71%29.aspx)