# Is there a way to set IsPreRelease in a .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

The [`FileVersionInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx) has an [`IsPreRelease` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.isprerelease.aspx).

Is there any way through AssemblyInfo or something else in my .NET assembly project to get that property to return true in the resulting .dll file?

Comment: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/set-specialbuild-versioninfo-c-vs-net-t1366417.html - The long way to go about it.  Not sure if anything's changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically need it in your project/solution, then the classic path is to create a Resource Script (.rc) file.  This is a homely, grungy format, but doable.  The downside is that you need to get all the correct settings to start with, then maintain them manually thereafter.

The easiest path, if you're okay with manual clicking after the build, is using [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) (or equivalent), and adding VS_FF_PRERELEASE into the FileFlags field.

Note, the FileFlagsMask field should already have the prerelease flag or'ed together with a batch of others--that's necessary, but not sufficient.

Also, you can use resedit to generate a starter .rc file pretty simply:

```
resedit -convert my.dll my.rc
```

If you need an auto-with-build process, then there may well be a utility out there that can make that targeted modification on the command line, and then you could add that as a post-build step on the project that builds the .dll in question.

Good luck!

Comment: I can't even test this at the moment (and frankly, I'm not even sure I remember which project I needed this for), but it looks solid. There's a helpful answer on how to use .rc files with C# projects over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390463/can-i-use-a-rc-resource-file-on-a-c-sharp-project

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use [resourcelib](https://github.com/dblock/resourcelib). This is a library to read and write reosurces including `Version (RT_VERSION)`.

**Update**

I'm not sure if you looked really at the source code.
But in the `resourcelib` there is a class called `FixedFileInfo.cs` which represents the [VS_FIXEDFILEINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646997(v=vs.85).aspx). In the documenation you can read, that the `IsPreRelease` is a value of the flag `dwFileFlags`.

Comment: It doesn't look like that lets' you set `IsPreRelease` though