# How to display control defined in rc file of C++ project in WPF C# project

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, rc

In my case, I have project A (in C#) that call a library from project B(C++). A interacted with B by C++/CLI method. In project B, we applied this code to avoid alert exception like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062034/what-does-afx-manage-stateafxgetstaticmodulestate-do-exactly):

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
```

However,in project B we have stored some interface control in MFC in a .rc file. Unfortunately, when I call the interface control of project B, it doesn't show in project A.

**Solution** (didn't work)
I have searched and find a solution like [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390463/can-i-use-a-rc-resource-file-on-a-c-sharp-project). In this case, they converted rc file to res file to import to project A. However, when applying RC tool we saw that all of include not found, unlike in Visual Studio.

How can I run project A and see interface control defined in .rc file of project B?

Comment: Does each and every public export of your DLL-project (B) set the appropriate module state? You should probably read [MFC Module State Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft1t4bbc.aspx) to learn, why this is necessary.